# retrieving the identifier of an element from application

Tags: c#, automation, element, identity

I'm learning to use Automation UI in C#. However the problem is that I can't identify a textbox within a side app properly.

I'm using following condition to identify a textbox:

```
string name = "textBox1";
Condition c = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, name);
```

It works fine in case if you know textbox's exact name, but you can't possibly know the exact name of the elements within an application other than your own. **None of the programs such as Spy++ or Winspector show this name!**

how do you identify textboxes within another application?

P.S. I've also tried to use "ClassNameProperty", but Class names are usually the same for similar elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app works great for that: [UISpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx)

Comment: thank you! i've tried spy++, Winspector, Window Detective and none of them worked! another alternative is "visual UI automation verify"